# Please help to understand ような grammar in this sentence

Tags: grammar

「そりゃ……あまねが喜んでくれることは、してあげたいと思わなくもないような、違うような、その反対なような……」

As i can translate this means something like "Very... i want to please Amane, looks like i kind of think about that..." but next parth translation with multiple ような　is absolutely unclear for me...

- そりゃ - very
- あまねが喜んでくれることは - to please Amane
- してあげたいと思わなくもないような - want to help to do, looks like i kind of think about that
- 違うような - ???
- その反対なような - ???

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ような normally means "like" "as if" or so.

However, in this context ような is abbreviation of ような気がする. So, "I kind of feel like doing sth to please あまね" is the meaning of the first phrase.

The rest of ような is also "feel like".
I can tell you that the rest of ような phrases imply speakers' ambivalent state of mind by negating the former, but I myself feel it's difficult to translate this to English.